# Where is the message definition stored?

Tags: ros, message, xmlrpc, roscore, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When a topic is advertised, are the md5 and the message definition of that message type stored somewhere accessible on the Ros server (By another node) or are they only sent with the message itself and checked every time a message is published?

Is there a way to get the message definition and the md5 without first receiving a message and without having to include the message header (working in c++)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270953/where-is-the-message-definition-stored?/) by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on ROS Answers with karma: 3339 on 2017-09-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `message_definition` is only exchanged when creating a [TCPROS connection](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Connection%20Header). For UDP transport there is no such information. Also the master doesn't store this information.

Depending on your scenario you might be able to load the message definition based on the topic type at runtime (in Python) if you can ensure that the system has the message package installed.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2017-09-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1